# How to remove or change font backcolor, paragraph background color or shading in MS Word?

Tags: fonts, ms-word, highlight, backcolor, shading

I copy / pasted some code examples from a website and the results include the backcolor shading on the text.  I would like to remove this backcolor.

[image]

Tried changing Paragraph shading, did not work.

Tried Font, Highlight color, did not work.

Tried a bunch of stuff and discovered the trick is in the details **so I wanted to share this solution.**

Comment: You're kind of missing all the details of your question here, because Word is a GUI application, so the way you do this is by selecting text and clicking the text/background color buttons. That's obviously _not_ what you're asking, so [describe your situation](/help/how-to-ask): what are you trying to do, what ([mcve]) code did you write to do that, what does it do when you run it (and how are you running it), and how is that different from expectation, and what did you already do in terms of debugging (and if that includes writing more code, show that code, too).

Comment: And for the "what are you trying to do", explain the _underlying_ activity. E.g. are you batch processing docx files using VB or C#? Are you writing a script that you run inside Word? Are you writing a script that you want to embed in a Word _document_? (And remember, all those details go in your post, don't put them in one or more reply comments)

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove text shading (backcolor, fill)**

**s1: Select TEXT only**

**IMPORTANT**: Use CTRL + SELECT to select each LINE (NOT PARAGRAPH MARK, turn on 'Show Paragaph marks'  )

**Tip**: This may be easier if 'Smart selection' is OFF (Options, Advanced, Editing options, Use smart paragraph selection)

**Tip**: It seems easier to select text only if you selet from the end of each line to the beginning

right

[image]

wrong

[image]

(if you select wrong (the Paragraph marks) you will not see the shading in the next step)

**s2: Home > Paragraphs, Borders (and shading)**

[image]

**s3: Change Fill to 'No Color'**

before

[image]

after

[image]

**Note:** If you don't see any shading be sure your did not select then entire paragraphs vs just the text.

**result**

[image]